# RESTful GET that can change system state?

Tags: rest

I am building a service that caches short lived data objects. The object creation process is expensive, so this service will cache them and other downstream applications can use them without managing their lifecycle.

The plan is that downstream apps will make a GET call to this service to fetch object. If the object is expired, the service will fetch a new object, cache it, and return it to the caller.

And Here is my dilemma - This way the GET operation changes system state, by fetching new object. I am sure that I am violating REST principles here, or is there a valid justification for this? Should I just change the method to POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This way the GET operation changes system state, by fetching new object. I am sure that I am violating REST principles here, or is there a valid justification for this? Should I just change the method to POST?

The short version: this is fine.

Longer version: REST says that our resources have common "uniform" semantics - the meaning of messages doesn't depend on which resource you reference.

In the case of HTTP, the primary discriminator for requests is the method.  For the [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) method, the semantics are (currently) described by RFC 7231.  GET is explicitly identified as being [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource.

If you, the server, need to change a bunch of your private information stores to compute the current representation of the resource, that's an implementation detail hidden behind the HTTP facade.  You can do what you like.

Fundamentally, what safe *means* is that anybody who knows the identifier can ask for the current representation of the resource at any time.  This allows browser to retry requests when the network is flaky, or for spiders to crawl around indexing the net, knowing that their requests do no harm (or more precisely, that the fault of any harms inflicted by those requests is properly assigned to the server).

If that's OK, then GET is a perfectly "RESTful" method to use for these requests.